# Wordpress: How to access a field from another post type? No ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Pods plugin to create a relationship between Users and the CPT 'galleries' by connecting them in my own CPT 'usersgallery'.

How can I, without using get_field form ACF, get the ID field from the gallery object that I got using:

```
$mytmp_selectobject = get_post_field('galerie');
```

// The next line should return the postID of the gallery object but when I run it, I get the ID of the current connection post type 'usersgallery' So I have to specify the source of the requested ID or am I on the wrong approach?

```
$mytmp_selectobjectid = get_post_field('ID', $mytmp_selectobject->ID);

echo $mytmp_selectobjectid;
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The `get_post_field` takes as a first argument the post field name. Is that in your case 'ID'? If you need to retrieve another post type and post id you should consider WP_Query

Comment: Yes exactly. Query worked for me.